# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - Plist

Tags: ios, swift, plist

i am trying to read from `propriety list` using swift but im getting this error, and thats the code im using to read from my `plist` :

Arrays i'm using :

```
var recipeNames :[String] = []
var recipeImages :[String] = []
var recipeTime :[String] = []
```

In viewDidload :

```
 var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("recipes", ofType: "plist")
    var dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
     recipeNames  = dict!.objectForKey("name")! as! [String]
     recipeImages  = dict!.objectForKey("image")! as! [String]
     recipeTime  = dict!.objectForKey("time")! as! [String]
```

Comment: Without plist itself, it is kinda hard to say whats wrong...

Comment: i'm trying the answer then if it didnt work i will upload screenshot of my plist.@NickCatib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be no error in your code, Check that the arrays in plist has the same naming as in your code might be mistaken something with keys.

You can check that by `right-click` on plist and `Open-as` then choose `source code`

Like : 
`objectForKey("name")` called `<key>name</key>` 
`objectForKey("image")` called  `<key>image</key>` 
`objectForKey("time")` called  `<key>time</key>`